# Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React Sample example - first try - login is already in progress

Tags: office-js

I have followed the instructions from here and registered an app via azure to test this Sample:

- link1: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React
- link2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2

1. **Register an application with the Microsoft Identity Platform**

- visit https://portal.azure.com/
- login with excel 365 acc
- [click ] on top left hand hamburger
- [select] - Azure Active Directory
- [scroll] to bottom of page to see icon - App registration
- [click] App registration
- [type name] Sample-Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React
- [select] - Accounts in any organizational directory
- [keep] - Web
- [type - redirect uri] https://localhost:3000/login/login.html
- [click] - register

2. **Copy client id to put into login/login.ts**

- [copy] Client ID
- [paste] login/login.ts clientId

3. **certs - https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/blob/master/src/docs/ssl.md#method-2-manually-install-the-certificate**

- cd to certs folder

```
cd Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React\certs
```

- [Dbl click] - ca.crt
- [click] Install certificate
- [Select] Local Machine
- [Select] Place all certificates in the following store
- [click] browse
- [Select] Trusted Root Certification Authorities
- [click] ok
- [click] next
- [click] Finish

```
The import was successful
```

You now have a self-signed certificate installed on your machine.

4. **run cmd as administrator: run node application**

```
yarn start
```

- Note: Did not opwn separate cmd window. Stayed in same.

5. **Open new cmd terminal - run sideload**

```
yarn run sideload
```

6. **in excel [click] - Open Add-in**
7. **[click - button] Connect to Office 365**

> errorMessage: login_progress_error message: Login_In_Progress: Error during login call - login is already in progress. errorCode: ClientAuthError: Login_In_Progress: Error during login call - login is already in progress. at AuthError (eval code:26:9) at ClientAuthError (eval code:106:9) at ClientAuthError.createLoginInProgressError (eval code:143:9) at UserAgentApplication.prototype.acquireTokenInteractive (eval code:333:13) at UserAgentApplication.prototype.loginRedirect (eval code:246:9) at Office.initialize (eval code:50:13) at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js:1782:41) at validateFunction (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js:306:21) at LoadScriptHelper.prototype.waitForFunction (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js:318:13) at appReady (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js:1778:25) .

I have looked in the other stackoverflow questions and github, and there is not a solution to this problem. Any advice.

I will post this in github also.

Comment: I went through your instructions exactly and mine ran fine with one exception, I had to allow the implicit grant options `Access tokens` and `ID tokens`.  I didn't see this in your instructions, did you do that?  It's under the Authentication tab on the Left Nav in the App on portal.azure.com.  

Another note, on my production app I had to change `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>`

Comment: @nikolifish Oh my god. Thankyou so much. It now works - mostly with removing .debug from path. This has been a bane in my side. Please post an answer to this and I'll upvote you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>` from the git example to the production url `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>` in your `Login.html` page.  You will likely have to do this in your `logout.html` page as well